# Javascript html table not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to total a list of die rolls (sum of pairs) in a table using javascript to avoid hard-coding 11 rows in my html page and accessing each row seperately later in the js file to add the values.
So I used a loop and document.writeln() to do this in a more compact way but the output doesn't show the table or anything.

```
document.writeln("<table border=\"1\"><thead><tr><th>Sum of Dice</th><th>Total Times   Rolled</th></tr></thead><tbody>");
for (var i=0; i < 11; i++)
{
    document.writeln("<tr><td>2</td><td></td></tr>");
}
document.writeln("</tbody></table>");
```

The rows shouldn't all start with 2, I only used that number as a test and the second  tag in the for loop is for the totals that I already have in an array but my issue is with displaying the table.

Comment: Please check your console for errors. Also `document.write()` is not the function you can use for tasks like this.

Comment: Well - your code seems to work just [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/wcJ7u/). where are you testing it ?

Comment: ewww. Oldskool, have you considered using a templating engine?

Comment: maybe its a timing issue. how are you calling it?

Comment: I'm calling it in the head of my HTML document:
<head>
  <script src="Problem4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

Comment: You need to move the script to the `body`, and make sure it's run during parsing, not after `onload` has been fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
        var code = "";
        function write(){
            code += "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Sum of Dice</th><th> Total Times Rolled</th></tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                code += "<tr><td>2</td><td></td></tr>";
            }
            code += "</table>";
            document.body.innerHTML = code;
        }
    </script>
```

And don`t forget to put this code to html:

```
<body onload="write()">
```

Here you have the result:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about this? This snippet ensures, that all previous content of the document is wiped out. Please check [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write).

Comment: Take a look on the picture

Comment: Please take a look at the real source code of your page after run this ; ).

Comment: I know, that this code overwrite all previous content, but i don`t know what Tarek Merachli wants to do, so i just helped him. If he want to keep all previous code, so he needs use innerHTML, but if he just want to make a table, this code is that what he was looking for

Comment: It showed the table but as mentioned by Teemu, it wiped out my paragraphs and heading

Comment: that i`m talking about, you need to use innerHTML like this:
document.body.innerHTML+="<tr><td>2</td><td></td></tr>" - all this in for-loop

Comment: Do I keep it in the function or put everything outside?

Answer (score 0):

I think create table by writeln with whole bunch of HTML text string is generally not a good idea. I would recommend create table dom element via Javascript and append it to the wrapper element.

```
var headerContent = ['Sum of Dice', 'Total Times Rolled'];
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    header = table.createTHead(),
    row, 
    cell;

table.border = 1;

// construct header
row = header.insertRow(0);
for (var i = 0, len = headerContent.length; i < len; i++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = headerContent[i];
}

// construct table content
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
    for (var j = 0, len = headerContent.length; j < len; j++) {
        cell = row.insertCell(j);
        cell.innerHTML = '2';
    }
}

// add table element to the dom tree
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.appendChild(table);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LgyuE/

Comment: Wow this is ridiculous, it works on jsfiddle but not in my file :/
I'm loading the js in the head element of my html file, should I be doing it in another way?

Comment: Execute this code when dom elements are loaded (when onload event triggers or $.ready() if you use jQuery), otherwise put it after your wrapper element.